# Windows 7 FTP server not able to serve large files to mac?

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-7.5

I setup my Windows 7 home premium 64-bit desktop to use Microsoft's IIS FTP server.  Works great except for big files... like 4gbyte files.  Only maybe 150mbytes end up getting transferred to Macs I need to retrieve these files to.

Is there a file size limit setting somewhere in IIS?  If I type `ls -l` I do see the full file size, but that's just not what ends up getting transferred:

```
ftp> ls -l
200 EPRT command successful.
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
06-30-12  02:16PM           4443150993 xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 72 bytes received in 0.00Seconds 72000.00Kbytes/sec.
ftp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just using FileZilla and everything worked perfect.